# python for-loop not executed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to write a python script that searches a txt file (english dictionary) for anagrams. I have those three functions:

```
def is_anagram(a,b):
    a_ = list(a)
    a_.sort()
    b_ = list(b)
    b_.sort()
    if a_ == b_ and a != b:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def find_anagrams(word,t):
    _res=[word]
    for line in t:
        check = line.strip()
        if is_anagram(check,word):
            _res += [check]
    return _res

def find_all_anagrams(f):
    res = {}
    void = []
    for line in f:
        word = line.strip()
        _list = list(word)
        _list.sort()
        key = tuple(''.join(_list))
        if key not in res and key not in void:
            if find_anagrams(word,f) == []:
                void += [key]
            res[key] = find_anagrams(word,f)
    return res
```

If i call the find_all_anagrams function with:

```
fin = open ('words.txt')
print find_all_anagrams(fin)
```

The program stops after the first loop and just gives me

```
{('a', 'a'): ['aa']}
```

Why does it not continue and process the second line of words.txt? Btw the words.txt file is the one from Moby Project that can be downloaded  here(http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt)

Answer (score 2):

When you call `find_all_anagrams` it will read the first line from file. Then it will call `find_anagrams` which will read the rest of the file. When the `for` loop in `find_all_anagrams` tries to pull next line from the file there's nothing more to read so it returns with the result generated so far.

Even if you'd change your program so that `find_all_anagrams` would continue from the following line it would be horribly slow because the time complexity is **O(n^2)**. Instead you could read the file once and store the words to dictionary where key is the sorted word and value is a list of words:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def key(word):
    return ''.join(sorted(word))

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('words.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        d[key(line)].append(line)

print d[key('dog')]
```

Output:

```
['dog', 'god']
```

Answer (score 0):

From within `find_all_anagrams(f)` you then pass `f` to `find_anagrams(word,f)`. In `find_anagrams` it then iterates over all the lines of the file on the line `for line in t:`

By the time it returns to find_all_anagrams, it's already read the entire file, and there is nothing left to read.

Comment: it seems to work like this. But strangely the find_anagrams function works flawlessly withouth the readlines method. Why is that?